# ngMaterial prompt box to add required field in the inputbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using ngMaterial to add prompt dialog box with input box name. name is required field and I am wondering if there is any function to do it easy way

```
 var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
        .title('Enter your name')
        .placeholder('name')
        **.required("required")**
        .ariaLabel('Name')
        .initialValue('jon')
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('Set')
        .cancel('No');
```

So when I click ok then it needs to highlight textbox in same way that it is arequired field.

I am working in angular 1.5

Comment: Maybe give us a link or a picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog .....on this page there is a prompt Dialog. In pop up dialog box , user has to enter name. I just want to add some way to mandate it.